# How to prevent substitution in echoed text

Tags: bash, scripting

I've written a bash script which contains

```
IP=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}'`
```

I've also written an installer for it:

```
echo "
echo "this is my script"
IP=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}'`
fi" > /tmp/myscript
```

However when I run it and I check the `myscript` file, it shows `IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` instead of the variable. So I assume I'm missing a tick or quote somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either escape your double quotes and substitution characters (`$`, `` ` ``) inside double quotes or use a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) (recommended):

```
cat >/tmp/myscript <<"END"
echo "this is my script"
IP=$( /sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}' )
END
```

Note that quoting the word `END` disables command and parameter expansion inside the here document. I have used the recommended `$( ... )` syntax for command expansion instead of the backticks (`` `...` ``) in this example.